# How to get VB class map: regions with declarations inside?

Tags: vb.net, class, dictionary, region

I need rapidly adopt myself to existing system written in VB. For some bigger classes of VB forms (2000+ lines) and others, I would like to get their **overview containing regions and declarations inside them** (methods, functions, properties and class-level variables) which I can print/save for reference.

Currently **I can achieve this manually** by deleting bodies of methods and removing comments. I am also able to use some advanced regex (regual expression) searches to mark desired lines, then filter the rest out. List of declarations can be obtained using **Reflection**, but I think it is always without `#Region` information.

Is there any VisualStudio functionality or external tool which can create such a 'class map' for me?

> In other words, I'd like to generate files similar to C/C++ headers but for VB and also including `#Region` information.

Example of expected output:

```
Public Class frmXY_Sample1

#Region "Internal Variables" 
#Region "Form Common"
    Private _Connection As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Private _DataFormType As XYZ.xyzDataFormType
    Private AllowEvents As Boolean
#End Region
#Region "Instance Data"
    Private _Instance As thisEnt
#End Region
#End Region

#Region "Form Events"
    Private Sub frmXY_SomeForm1_Load(sender As Object _
#End Region
#Region "Save..."
    Private Sub ID_Save_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ID_Save.Click
#End Region

#Region "FormTabs" 
#Region "Tab 'SampleTab1'"
    Private Sub TS_TAB1_AddNew_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Private Sub TS_TAB1_Detail_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
#End Region
#Region "Tab 'SampleTab2'"
    Private Sub TS_TAB2_Detail_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Private Sub TS_TAB2_Refresh_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Private Sub TAB2_Grid_CellPainting(sender As System.Object _
#End Region
```

Thank you.

Comment: What Version or Visual Studio are you using. (ex. Visual Studio 2012 Professional).

Comment: I'm using 2012 Professional (and can access 2008 Professional, too). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing exactly like you are looking for in Visual Studio 2012 Professional.  If you are working in a C# project, you can automatically get a code map similar to what you are looking for with the "Go To Definition" feature.

Here is a snippet of C# code.

[image]

Pressing F12 while the cursor is on the StreamReader class causes the following metadata editor to open.

[image]

**Use Go To Definition to decode VB class**

The VB editor also has a Go To Definition, but it takes you to the Object Browser instead of the metatdata window.  But there is a way to get the metadata.

Create a separate C# project.  In my example, I made a simple Console application.
Add a reference to your VB project 
Write some code in the C# project to instantiate a type in the VB library and use the C# F12 to get the metadata

Here is a simple VB class.

[image]

This is the C# code referring to the Printer class.
[image]

Here is the metadata from the VB class, from within the C# project.

[image]

I know this is not as complete as your example, but it's a start.

**Other solutions**

There is a Code Map extension you can install from the `Tools\Extensions and Updates` menu.  I don't think it supports the printing option you want however.

Finally, you can create your own Visual Studio extension.  This is not a trivial task though.  Download the [Visual Studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb166441%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you want to learn more.

Comment: great value, Walt, backed by time you spent - thank you! also thanks for pointing to that extension